# How to update a staticResource via apex

Tags: apex

Creating a tool for some QA people to check a subset of a system. Normally I would just create a test class and everything would be fine. However, the process is incredibly convoluted and in order to isolate things our team decided to use a static Resource which has what items need to be tested, and what the special data needed is. Since the QA devs plan to test 100+ items at the same time it's not really feasible to tell them to look at the dev logs after running the test. Therefore they wanted me to update the file they had uploaded with the additional information. I would just email the file to the user but the sandbox does not allow email sending apparently and the people with the authority to change that if its allowed are not in right now.

TLDR:
I have a static resource which I need to get content from, do some processing on, and then update the file with the new information. Can I do this? I haven't been able to find any ways to do this.

Comment: Hi denver, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. You may also wish to read up on what an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) is. Currently, you have explained how you are trying to solve a problem, but not what problem you are trying to solve. What is your end goal, and why did you conclude using `StaticResource` was the correct approach?

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, I've used SE before and have seen questions that were simpler than that, and just didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Should the static resource route turn out to be the right choice, static resources can be updated from many languages via the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm). That includes Apex, though the standard [Apex Metadata API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api) AFAIK doesn't include static resources yet; I've used [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for those.